# Display multiple values in a single column if the UserID matches?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to display multiple values (from different rows in a DB) in the same column (in an html table) separated by a comma (, ) if UserID == UserID?
For example:

Database:

```
UserID | Skills

   1      java
   1      python
   2      SQL
   1      HTML
```

HTML Table:

```
UserID | Skills

   1      java, python, HTML
   2      SQL
```

**UPDATE:** Since using `GROUP_CONCAT` as such:

```
$user_project_sql = "SELECT user.UserID, user.Fname, user.Lname, user.JobRole, GROUP_CONCAT(skills.Description SEPARATOR ', ') as skills
      FROM user
      INNER JOIN userprojects ON user.UserID = userprojects.UserID
      INNER JOIN projects ON userprojects.ProjectID = projects.ProjectID
      INNER JOIN userskills ON user.UserID = userskills.UserID
      INNER JOIN skills ON userskills.SkillID = skills.SkillID
      INNER JOIN usertasks ON user.UserID = usertasks.UserID
      INNER JOIN tasks ON usertasks.TaskID = tasks.TaskID
      WHERE tasks.TaskID = '$Task'
      GROUP BY UserID"
      or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I am getting all the skills printed twice:

```
UserID | Skills

       1      java, python, HTML, java, python, HTML
       2      SQL
```

Comment: yes, possible. you have to GROUP_CONCAT to achieve this

Comment: There's many ways to do this `GROUP_CONCAT` is probably the quickest

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
select UserID,GROUP_CONCAT(Skills) as skills from table where UserID='YOU_USER_ID' group by UserID;
```

Comment: Add UserID in selection

Comment: by default the `group_concat` added the fields as comma, but here you have to mention it like we did..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to look into `GROUP_CONCAT` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

I think you can achieve the desired result with

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(`Skills` SEPARATOR ", ") as `skills` 
  FROM `skillsTable` 
  WHERE `UserID` = ? 
  GROUP BY `UserID`
```

The GROUP BY is optional and unecessary if only selecting a single user id. Useful if you, for example, do `WHERE UserID IN (. . . )`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have one issue (that I am hoping you may assist me with) since implementing your suggestion; see OP edit.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT(expr)

This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values. The full syntax is as follows:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Skills ORDER BY Skills ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as Skills FROM table
```

This is a query that also sort the `Skills` according to alphabets of Skills.